# "System is not defined" when building RESTful APIs with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I am trying to build RESTful APIs using TypeScript and SystemJS

```js
// index.ts
// Import express
import express from "express"
// Imports routes
import apiRoutes from "api-routes.js"

// Initialise the app
const app = express()

// set up server port
const port = process.env.port || 3000

// Send message for default URL
app.get('/', (request, response) => response.send('Hello World with Express.'))

// Launch app to listen to specified port
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})

// Use API routes in the app.
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)
```

This file gets compiled to javascript

```
System.register(["express", "api-routes.js"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var express_1, api_routes_js_1, app, port;
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (express_1_1) {
                express_1 = express_1_1;
            },
            function (api_routes_js_1_1) {
                api_routes_js_1 = api_routes_js_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            // import * as express from "express"
            // import * apiRoutes from './build/'
            // Initialise the app
            app = express_1.default();
            // set up server port
            port = process.env.port || 3000;
            // Send message for default URL
            app.get('/', function (request, response) { return response.send('Hello World with Express.'); });
            // Launch app to listen to specified port
            app.listen(port, function () {
                console.log("Listening on port " + port);
            });
            // Use API routes in the app.
            app.use('/api', api_routes_js_1.default);
        }
    };
});
```

I get the below error

[image]

It says I am unable to refer `system` from system module.
Here is the link to my [repo](https://github.com/anirudha-music/RESTful_API/tree/feature/develop)

In `html` I import the SystemJS like so

`<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>`

How do I import SystemJS in my `index.ts` file?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand the question. A REST API runs on the server, so why do you need to use systemJS? Node can load ES6 modules in different ways as well and hopefully native very soon.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that it doesn't work

Comment: Can't you use `"module": "commonjs"` in your `tsconfig.json`? When you define to `system`, it will transpile targeting SystemJS, which is a module loader to provide compatibility for ES modules on browsers. As your API is going to work in a Node server, you should be able to change it to `commonjs` without breaking changes

Comment: I created a [pull request](https://github.com/anirudha-music/RESTful_API/pull/1) in your repository with a working version

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto It worked thank you so much.

Comment: Okay so as your code will run on node server, you don't need to use SystemJS. Using commonJS & ES5 will convert typescript keywords like import and export? Where I can find this changes on internet?

Comment: You can have a look on Typescript [modules documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). On the chapter "Code Generation for Modules", it explains the differences of the resulting code based on the module target specified